# Converting rules from apache to nginx

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have problem with these rules:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500.html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is the problem? What nginx rules have you tried?

Comment: Nothing works.
I tried online converters and:
  if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^.*$ /index.php last;
  }
and
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

Comment: Please update your question with _specific_ problems, as well as configurations you've tried. At the moment it reads as "it doesn't work, fix it for me".

Answer (score 1):

Directive

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/500.html
```

transforms to

```
error_page 500 http://example.com/500.html;
```

Rewrite from www to non-www server name

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

transforms to this `server` section:

```
server {
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri?;
}
```

And rewrite block

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

turns into

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri?;
```

So the resulting nginx config will look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  www.example.com;
    rewrite ^ http://example.com$request_uri?;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  example.com;

    root /var/www/example.com;
    error_page 500 http://example.com/500.html;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request_uri?;   
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        #
        # PHP processing here
        #
    }       
}
```